# Why can a static variable inside a class method keep its initial reference assigned?

Tags: objective-c

Here comes the code snap

```
+(instancetype)sharedStore{
   static BNRItemStore*sharedStore=nil;
    if(!sharedStore){
        sharedStore=[[self alloc]initPrivate];
    }
    return sharedStore;
}
```

I'm wondering how variable 'sharedStore' can can keep the reference assigned to itself, no matter how many times method is executed.

It seems such variable is static but in Java such variable is temp and extinguish when exiting method...Even more, if sharedStore is assigned to nil firstly then set to an instance then, why nil can not be then set to the variable again when entering method next? how can it keep the reference as a method variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `static` keyword means something completely different in C than it does in Java.

In a function (method) scope, it means that the variable is persistent, which it means it retains its value even after execution leaves the scope of the function.

At the file (compilation unit) level, it creates a variable that is visible to all code in the file, but is private to that file.  That means that another file declaring a static variable of the same name creates a second variable.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually treated as if the `static` variable was a global variable, as it's stored in the heap (or probably data segment; thanks @jlehr) and not the stack:

```
BNRItemStore*sharedStore=nil;
+(instancetype)sharedStore{

    if(!sharedStore){
        sharedStore=[[self alloc]initPrivate];
    }
    return sharedStore;
}
```

It's only visible from within the method, however.

Comment: Static variables are generally stored in the data segment, definitely not in heap.

Comment: @jlehr Yeah that makes sense; thanks.

Comment: Heap is used exclusively for dynamic memory allocation under program control. Data segments are allocated by the compiler. The compiler can't dynamically allocate memory, so it can't allocate in heap.

Comment: More to the point though, I think the OP is mostly puzzled by the initialization, which to the casual observer might appear to be executed every time the method is entered. In fact though, the initialization is done at compile time, not at run time.

Comment: @jlehr Doesn't laying out the code, as in my answer, make that clearer?